# CSS tooltip displaying behind text with one class and above text with another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `font-awesome` to display an "icon" that, when hovered over, will display a tooltip.  All of this is achieved using CSS.

When the tooltip is displayed above the item (`.top` class) everything works fine and the tooltip being displayed appears over top of the page text. However, when I display the tooltip below the item (`.bottom` class), the the tooltip is displayed but the font-awesome icons of the page appear over top of the tooltip.

I can't figure out why it works one way and not the other.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: help;
  z-index:10;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  min-width: 400px;
  z-index:10;
}

.tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 9px solid #000;
  display: none;
  z-index:10;
}

.tooltip:hover:before, .tooltip:hover:after{
    display: block;
}

.tooltip.right:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.tooltip.right:after {
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 100%;
}

.tooltip.bottom::before {
  top: 80%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tooltip.bottom::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
  top: 80%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.tooltip.top::before {
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.tooltip.top::after {
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: 80%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Tooltip Top 1 <span class="tooltip top" data-text="this is tip one."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Bottom 1 <span class="tooltip bottom" data-text="this is tip two."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Bottom 2 <span class="tooltip bottom" data-text="this is tip one."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Top 2 <span class="tooltip top" data-text="this is tip two."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everyone `.tooltip` has its own independent [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), within which the positioning of nested elements and pseudo-elements is coordinated.
And since everyone `.tooltip` has the same `z-index`, then they are arranged among themselves in order, i.e. the last element will be higher than the rest.

In order for your popup elements to have a single context in which they can be consistent with each other using `z-index`, it is enough for `.tooltip` to remove `z-index` (or set to `auto`) and then the closest context will be the root element of the document (`<html>`).

If you really need a `z-index` for the whole group, you just need to set the `z-index` for the nearest common root element (in your case, this is `.container`).

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: help;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  min-width: 400px;
  z-index:10;
}

.tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 9px solid #000;
  display: none;
  z-index:10;
}

.tooltip:hover:before, .tooltip:hover:after{
    display: block;
}

.tooltip.right:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.tooltip.right:after {
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 100%;
}

.tooltip.bottom::before {
  top: 80%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tooltip.bottom::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
  top: 80%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.tooltip.top::before {
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.tooltip.top::after {
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: 80%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Tooltip Top 1 <span class="tooltip top" data-text="this is tip one."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Bottom 1 <span class="tooltip bottom" data-text="this is tip two."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Bottom 2 <span class="tooltip bottom" data-text="this is tip one."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Tooltip Top 2 <span class="tooltip top" data-text="this is tip two."><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
```

Comment: Your answer didn't make it abundantly clear, but the solution seemed to lie in adding the z-index to the `.tooltip:hover` CSS class definition.

Comment: @RHarris, I have updated the answer, with a more detailed explanation. Elements that are in independent of each other "stacking context" cannot be forcibly positioned above or below each other using the `z-index`. I.e. in your case, one `.tooltip:before` 
 couldn't influence another `.tooltip:before`, because they are in different contexts. To make this possible, they need to be combined into one `stacking context`. This can be either the root of the document (by default) or the nearest common positioned element with a `z-index`.

Comment: How the stacking context is formed can be read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: So I'm not sure exactly how this worked then, but I was able to solve this without adding a `z-index` value to the container.  I simply added `z-index` to the `.tooltip:hover` and it resolved my issue.